# Find the sum using Fourier series

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis

I got the Fourier series for $x^2$ on the interval $[-1,1]$:

$$x^2 = \frac{1}{3}+\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\cos(n\pi x)}{n^2}$$
and I'm supposed to find the sum of:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^3}.$$

I would think it would be normal to take the integral of both sides of the Fourier series from $-1$ to $1$, but in the solution sheet the take the integral from $-1/2$ to $1/2$, and says it would be wrong to take the integral from $-1$ to $1$. How come that?

Comment: For any positive integer $n$, the integral of $\cos(n\pi x)$ over $[-1,1]$ is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Because $$\int_{-1}^1\cos(n\pi x)\,dx=\frac2{n\pi}\sin(n\pi)=0,\qquad n\geq 1.$$
Integration from $-1$ to $1$ gives us nothing but $\int_{-1}^1x^2\,dx=\int_{-1}^1\frac13\,dx=\frac23,$ which doesn't help us to find the value of the series.

However,
$$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\cos(n\pi x)\,dx=\frac2{n\pi}\sin(n\pi/2),\qquad n\geq 1$$
So
$$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}x^2\,dx=\frac13+\frac8{\pi^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right)}{n^3}=\frac13-\frac8{\pi^3}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k-1)^3},$$
where we used the fact that, if $n=2k$ for $k\geq1$, then $\sin(n\pi/2)=\sin(k\pi)=0$; if $n=2k-1$ for $k\geq 1$, then
$$\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right)=\sin\left(k\pi-\frac\pi2\right)=(-1)^k\sin\left(-\frac\pi2\right)=(-1)^{k+1},$$
and $(-1)^n=(-1)^{2k-1}=-1$.
Now, we can get the value of the series easily:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}.$$

Btw, it is also OK to integrate from $0$ to $1/2$. We are not always integrating on the whole interval where the Fourier expansion holds. We derive the Fourier expansion, and then we use it, in a way depending more on "what we want", rather than "what we have".

Comment: olay thank you. that makes a lot of sense! and thank you for the tips. I just have one more question. How do you get that these to are equal?

$$\frac13+\frac8{\pi^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right)}{n^3}=\frac13+\frac8{\pi^3}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k-1)^3}.$$

Isnt $$sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})=(-1)^{n+1}$$

Comment: @Lisa See my editted answer. Note that $\sin(n\pi+\frac\pi2)=(-1)^n$, not $\sin(\frac{n\pi}2)$. You may remember it incorrectly. For example, $\sin(\frac{2\pi}2)=\sin(\pi)=0\neq (-1)^{2+1}$.

Comment: im sorry im a bit confused. i agree that $$sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}))= n^{n+1}$$  
but dont know how 
$$(-1)^n *(-1)^{n+1}= (-1)^{n+1}$$
and how
$$n^3 = (2n-1)^3$$

Comment: @Lisa I splitted the sum to odd part and even part: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right)}{n^3} =\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{2k}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}2\right)}{(2k)^3}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{2k-1}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2k-1\pi}2\right)}{(2k-1)^3}.$$When we sum on $n=2k$, we get $0$, since $\sin(k\pi)=0$. For the odd part $n=2k-1$, we get the sum $-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k-1)^3}$. Finally, the sum is independent on the symbol of index, so it equals to $$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^3}.$$

Comment: thank u for a good explantion! you really helped me! <3

Comment: @Lisa You're welcome. I'm very glad to help!